# error starting weblogic server in Eclipse

Tags: weblogic

When  I try to start the webLogic server. i got the error in the cosole:

> La l¡nea escrita es demasiado larga. No se esperaba :process_path  en
>   este momento.

In the eclipse logs. show

> Server Oracle WebLogic Server 12c R2 (12.2.1.2) [utn_domain] failed to
>   start.

and show me also

> Either the server process could not be started or it terminated
>   abruptly. Check the start script.

i create a new doamin but the error persist. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the log file which is automatically created in domain log folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try DefaultDomain as follow unless you have created user_project.
..\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain